# Android: ConcurrentModificationException error

Tags: android, kotlin, concurrentmodification

I'm scratching my head here trying to understand why I'm getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` here...

This is my code:

```
var adapterCurrentList : PagedList<WorkPackagesQuery.WorkPackage>? = null
val workPackagesArrayList = arrayListOf<WorkPackagesQuery.WorkPackage>()

fun turnPagedListIntoArrayList(searchString: String) {
    workPackagesArrayList.clear()
    val tempCurrentArray = Collections.synchronizedList(adapterCurrentList)
    synchronized(tempCurrentArray) {

        for ((index, workPackage) in tempCurrentArray.withIndex()) { //exception is thrown here. 
            if (workPackage.id().contains(searchString)) {
                workPackagesArrayList.add(workPackage)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What am I missing?  I am not modifying `tempCurrentArray` while iterating over it... First time through, with `searchString`, it runs fine, the second time, with a different `searchString`, it throws the exception.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bechtel.pf.mock, PID: 18686
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1057)
    at androidx.paging.PagedStorage.get(PagedStorage.java:170)
    at androidx.paging.PagedList.get(PagedList.java:410)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
    at com.bechtel.pf.ui.workpackages.WorkPackagesViewModel.turnPagedListIntoArrayList(WorkPackagesViewModel.kt:48)
    at com.bechtel.pf.ui.workpackages.WorkPackagesViewModel.pareDownArrayForSearch(WorkPackagesViewModel.kt:59)
    at com.bechtel.pf.ui.workpackages.WorkPackagesFragment$onCreateView$$inlined$addTextChangedListener$1.afterTextChanged(TextView.kt:101)
```